# Bot connector API: Send message to aadObjectId directly

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to send a bot message directly to an Azure Active Directory Object ID?

Comment: What do you mean by sending message to AadObject ID? Are you trying to send message using Bot to a user?

Comment: If yes you can try sending message to user with user ID([fetch it from roaster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet)) with [Sending proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet)

Answer (score 1):

You can send message using [proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) as Trinetra mentioned in his comments.
To send Proactive message basically you need user ID in case you want to send it to 1:1  and team/channel id in case you want to send it in channel or to team.
I assume your scenario is 1:1 - for this to get user id you can use following line of code

> var member = await TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.From.Id, cancellationToken);

For more details please refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-single-member-details).